# Java - Find a process responsible for editing a file & kill it if possible?

Tags: java, watchservice

I've been working on Java's WatchService API to monitor a file directory to see when files have been modified within it. (On Windows). I've got it so that I can see when files are modified.

How can I see which process is responsible for file modification, and kill the process, even perhaps create a dump file too?

Comment: did you try anything to do that?

Comment: If you can find out the PID, then you can use [`ProcessHandle.of(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#of(long)) (Java 9+). The actual finding of the PID will likely require native code, if it's possible to do what you want.